# Cassandra adding new Datacenter with even token distribution

Tags: cassandra

We have a 1 DC cluster running Cassandra 3.11. The DC has 8 nodes total with 16 tokens per node and 3 seed nodes. We use Murmur3Partitioner.

In order to ensure better data distribution for the upcoming cluster in another DC, we want to use the tokens allocation approach where you manually specify initial_token for seed nodes and use allocate_tokens_for_keyspace for non seed nodes.

The problem is that our current datacenter cluster is not well balanced, since we built the cluster without a tokens allocation approach. So currently this means that the tokens are not well distributed. I can't figure out how to calculate initial_token for the new seed nodes in the new Datacenter. I probably cannot consider the token range of the new cluster as independent and calculate the initial token range as I would for a fresh cluster. At this point I am very unsure how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Currently, I am trying to make a concept of migration and have come to the part where I do not know what to do and the documentation is not helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to https://dba.stackexchange.com instead. But don't be concerned, I'm just letting you know for future reference. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I prepared the question in dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

There are scripts available to calculate the initial_token value, for example, you could use the one here to quickly calculate these values:
https://www.geroba.com/cassandra/cassandra-token-calculator/

You do have the ability to set allocate_tokens_for_keyspace and point it to a keyspace with a replication factor you plan to use for user-created keyspaces in the cluster, if you're adding a new DC, then you probably already have such a keyspace, and this should help you get better distribution.  Remember to set this before bootstrapping nodes to the new DC.

Another option would be to avoid using vnodes entirely and go with single token architecture by setting num_tokens to 1. This gives you the ability to bootstrap nodes to the new DC, load/stream data and then monitor the distribution and make changes as needed using 'nodetool move':
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/tools/nodetool/move.html

This method would require you to monitor the distribution and make changes to the token assignments as needed, and you'd want to follow-up the move command with 'nodetool repair' and 'nodetool cleanup' on all nodes, but it gives you the ability to rectify uneven distribution quickly without bootstrapping new nodes.  You would still want to use the same method for calculating the initial_token values with single-token architecture and set that before bootstrap.
I suspect either method could work well for you, but wanted to give you a second option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
This goes in the direction as I have already thought, but was not sure. You said "Remember to set this before bootstrapping nodes to the new DC." This probably needs to be set in the current DC and the upcoming DC? Does this redistribute the tokens in the current DC?

Comment: Once the nodes are bootstrapped it won't have any affect, so you don't need to set it in the existing DC, just set it before bootstrapping nodes to the new DC.
If it were the first node in the entire cluster, then you'd bootstrap that initial seed node, create the keyspace with the proper RF, then set it on all other nodes before bootstrapping.

Comment: Ok got it. However, when the first node in the new DC is booted, there is no keyspace for allocate_tokens_for_keyspace yet. And when the node gets a keyspace replicated from the old DC the bootstrap process is already finished and allocate_tokens_for_keyspace was ignored? How to work around this problem?

Comment: You can adjust your keyspace replication factor to include the new DC before bootstrapping the initial node to the DC.

Comment: I came across this article which takes a similar approach to the one you wrote. The difference is that there for the seed node with initial_tokens the tokens are set manually during bootstrapping. Is this necessary to get a better balanced cluster?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the link.
https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/02/21/set-up-a-cluster-with-even-token-distribution.html

Comment: If you wanted manually calculate the tokens before bootstrapping, yes, that does often result in better distribution, but isn't mandatory.  If you use single token architecture, then you have the ability to adjust dynamically after the data is loaded, which can be a nice feature to take advantage of.